# .load within a loop only seems to fire on the last loop

Tags: jquery, templates, mustache

I'm having a problem looping with a .load function inside the loop. I'm passing in a value from a listbox wich indicates the amount of sections to create. I'm using Moustache to load the template from a seperate file. This should create the amount of sections in the listbox but all I end up with is the last section created and none of the others. Following the code through the debugger the .load function doesn't want to fire until the last pass of the loop. The listbox on.(change) is as follows:

```
$(document).on('change', '#SCTotSections', function () {
var sectNumToCreate = parseInt($('#SCTotSections :selected').val(), 10);
var startNumSections = parseInt(startSectNum, 10);
var currentAddSection = startNumSections + 1;
var postTo = '#writeToTest';
if (sectNumToCreate < startNumSections)
{
    if (startNumSections != sectNumToCreate )
    {
        var myNode = document.getElementById("S" + startNumSections)
        myNode.remove();
        //while (myNode.firstChild) {
        //    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
        //}
        startSectNum = startSectNum - 1;
        startNumSections = startNumSections - 1;
    }
}
else if (sectNumToCreate > startNumSections)
{
    while (startNumSections != sectNumToCreate)
    {
        var data = {
            section: currentAddSection
        };

        $("#templates").load("../SCSectionTemplate #SCSectionTemplate", function () {
            var template = document.getElementById('SCSectionTemplate').innerHTML;
            var output = Mustache.render(template, data);
            $(postTo).html(output);
        });

        currentAddSection = currentAddSection + 1;
        startSectNum = startSectNum + 1;
        startNumSections = startNumSections + 1;


    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems that I can see.

- You are overriding the contents of postto in the loop instead of appending to it.
- The use of the closure variable `data` in the loop is not correct(See [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake) & [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)).

So try

```
$(document).on('change', '#SCTotSections', function () {
    var sectNumToCreate = parseInt($('#SCTotSections :selected').val(), 10);
    var startNumSections = parseInt(startSectNum, 10);
    var currentAddSection = startNumSections + 1;
    var postTo = '#writeToTest';
    if (sectNumToCreate < startNumSections) {
        if (startNumSections != sectNumToCreate) {
            var myNode = document.getElementById("S" + startNumSections)
            myNode.remove();
            //while (myNode.firstChild) {
            //    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
            //}
            startSectNum = startSectNum - 1;
            startNumSections = StartNumSections - 1;
        }
    } else if (sectNumToCreate > startNumSections) {
        //clear the container
        $(postTo).empty('');
        while (startNumSections != sectNumToCreate) {
            var data = {
                section: currentAddSection
            };

            //use a local closure for the data variable
            (function (data) {
                $("#templates").load("../SCSectionTemplate #SCSectionTemplate", function () {
                    var template = document.getElementById('SCSectionTemplate').innerHTML;
                    var output = Mustache.render(template, data);
                    //keep appending new items from the loop
                    $(postTo).append(output);
                });
            })(data);

            currentAddSection = currentAddSection + 1;
            startSectNum = startSectNum + 1;
            startNumSections = startNumSections + 1;


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks So much for this. This has worked. I have a lot to learn still so your help is greatly appreciated.